# If-statements inside a switch in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a context based menu that is displayed based on the current active controller like this:

```
@switch (this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "unitdetails":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "operation":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "trend":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "wellguide":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "setup":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "site":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "alarms":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "asx":
                        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
                        break;
                    case "reports":
                }
```

Worked fine up until today, where I came across a problem. My controller has a few different actions, but the menu is not to be displayed with all of the them. So, I need to do a check inside the "reports" case to check if the current action is supposed to Render my `_ContextMenu`.

Would something along the lines of this be appropriate:

```
case "reports":
    if (this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower() == "unitactivity")
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        goto default;
    }
```

I cannot seem to get this working, as it throws an exception saying (Note: I removed the namespaces):
`Message='UnitActivityModel' does not contain a definition for 'ViewUnitContract'`

This works fine with all the other cases in the switch, but the trouble arises when starting to check the current action. Any suggestions? The other controllers use the same `UnitActivityModel`, strongly typed in view.

Comment: What exactly is the point of that `switch` statement? It does the same thing regardless of the `case`...?

Comment: It's supposed to display the same partial view for all of those controllers. Might be a bit messy, but that's the way I got it to work in the first place :)

Comment: @NicklasWinger then do not repeat same code for all cases. Use instead `case "unitdetails": case "site": ... case "asx": Html.RenderPartial("_ContextMenu"); break;`

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, do it in the controller. This code does not belong in the view.

Comment: Allrighty. I'll try refactoring it alltogether and get back here with the solution. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg Any suggestions as to where I could go for some relevant information on a menu structure like the one I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting that much decision making code in a view is generally a bad idea. Where possible leave the view for data and push decision-making back to the controllers (or worst case into a partial view, yuk).

In your case, instead of `Html.RenderPartial` try something like

```
@Html.Action("ContextMenu", "Menu", new { id = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower() })
```

or of you prefer inline code-style:

```
Html.RenderAction("ContextMenu", "Menu", new { id = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower() });
```

This will pass the current controller name to your `MenuController.ContextMenu(string id)` action method, where id receives the controller name.

My personal preference is to have meaningful parameter names using `[Bind]` (I hate the generic `id`):

e.g.

```
MenuController.ContextMenu([Bind(Prefix="id")]string controllerName)
```

You can then make decisions in your menu controller and return a partial (or one of many partials), or even `return EmptyResult()` (for no menu).

The result of this extra controller call gets rendered in place, just like any other Partial View.